# How does ls -l sorts files?

Tags: file, unix, ls

I have question about sorting files by ls -l. I read in manual that it divides directories and non-directories and sorts them in lexicographic order separately, but run into situation where ls doesn't follow this rule, here is example:
[image]

First files, then directories and then files again

Why it displays like this?

Comment: *I read in manual* Which manual?  It may have applied to a version of `ls` on a different operating system.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Manual in terminal after command  >man ls

Comment: This is what it currently says (on macOS): "If _more than one operand is given_, non-directory operands are
     displayed first; directory and non-directory operands are sorted separately and in lexicographical order." (emphasis mine). So it will only apply this rule if you give some "operands" on the command line. E.g. `ls -l some.directory some.file` will list **some.file**, and then sorted content of **some.directory**

Comment: @tromgy Got it, but I still need to understand how ls sorting works

Comment: @ФедяСтарик, it seems that by default `ls -l` it will sort everything (regardless if it's a file or a directory) alphabetically, e.g. A-Z first, then a-z

Comment: @tromgy Could it be considered that it sorts in ASCII order from low to high?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is a more precise statement than "alphabetically"

Comment: **It depends on the locale set** for your shell process, which if not changed (explicitly by you, or by your `.profile` or similar) is a systemwide default. Do `locale` to see what is currently set. Usually all the vars are set the same, but if different for this case the precedence is LANGUAGE (GNU only) > LC_ALL > LC_COLLATE > LANG. If that specifies ASCII sorting (canonically `C`), programs like `ls` do ASCII sorting; if it specifies a language-based or country-specific sorting, programs do that language-based or country-specific sorting (often case-insensitive).

Answer (score 0):

The sorting order depends on hosts' locale.

In my Linux host the sorting order is by [UTF-8](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp), upper case Letters are before lower case letters.

#### In addition

Suggesting to try:

```
\ls -l
```

And check the results.

#### Explanation:

In most interactive shells. `ls` is an `alias` that adds coloring and sorting.

Typing `\ls` overides the `alias`

It is possible to inspect the specific `alias` with

```
alias ls
```